# convert from std::string to String^

Tags: string, c++-cli, managed-c++

I have a function in C++ that have a value in std::string type and would like to convert it to String^.

```
void(String ^outValue)
{
   std::string str("Hello World");
   outValue = str;
}
```

Comment: I think you need another tag because `String^` doesn't make much sense in C++.

Comment: This is managed c++ syntax. And your function isn't even valid, there is no identifier.

Comment: The problem is that this function is used to convert a value from C++ to C#/ I mean this function is called by C# program

Comment: @juanchopanza it also exists in WinRT, and probably should call .c_str(); on the std::string

Comment: @JoachimPileborg well, I'm sure there's a tag for that!

Comment: @Moti I would have added the tag for you, but I know nothing about C#, .NET, RT or whatever. So better if you do so.

Comment: @Aesthete it's also winRT syntax

Comment: @Moti when you call this function from your c# code, are you passing in the string by reference or by value?

Comment: @johnathon - Yeah I'm reading all about it now. I have already changed the tags for the question, but I'll let the OP or someone else change it to winRT / CLI - as I'm not 100% what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Googling reveals [marshal_as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx) (untested):

```
// marshal_as_test.cpp
// compile with: /clr
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

int main() {
   std::string message = "Test String to Marshal";
   String^ result;
   result = marshal_as<String^>( message );
   return 0;
}
```

Also see [Overview of Marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx).

Comment: This no longer compiles.

Answer (score 15):

From MSDN:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string str = "test";
   String^ newSystemString = gcnew String(str.c_str());
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235219.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As far as I got it, at least the marshal_as approach (not sure about gcnew String) will lead to non ASCII UTF-8 characters in the std::string to be broken.

Based on what I've found on https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/725734-utf-8-std-string-system-string I've build this solution which seems to work for me at least with German diacritics:

```
System::String^ StdStringToUTF16(std::string s)
{

 cli::array<System::Byte>^ a = gcnew cli::array<System::Byte>(s.length());
 int i = s.length();
 while (i-- > 0)
 {
    a[i] = s[i];
 }

 return System::Text::Encoding::UTF8->GetString(a);
}
```