# C++ login interface using windows applications

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to do a c++ login interface using windows application forms on visual studio 2013. The problem is that i am trying to compare the value in the textbox to the line in the file but i am getting an error that the operands type are incompatible.

```
 private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        string un, pw;

        ifstream read("file.txt");
        getline(read, un);
        getline(read, pw);


        if (textBox1->Text = un && textBox2->Text = pw){

            MessageBox::Show("You have successfully login!", "Login Message", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Information);

        }

        else {
            MessageBox::Show("Incorrect Password or Username !", "Login Message", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
                    }

        read.close();


    }
```

Comment: If you are not good at C++ and do not want to learn the language, why code in it?

Comment: If you have compiler errors you should share them.  It is not nice to horde the errors.

Comment: @NathanOliver, want a share of mine? :)

Comment: @SergeyA Sure.  They have to be true errors though. Not warnings treated as errors ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver You are not making it easy for me. Would you accept ICEs?

Comment: I question your choice of *operators*, not *operands*.

Comment: @SergeyA , they *aren't* learning C++. Note the `^`.

Comment: @user4581301, so much true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things going wrong here:

```
if (textBox1->Text = un && textBox2->Text = pw){
```

Problem 1: `un` is a `std::string`, [a C++ standard library string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and `textBox1->Text` is `System::String ^`, a managed pointer to [a .Net string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx).

The types are very different and not implicitly (automatically) comparable. You need to convert one to the to the other to compare them. Seeing as it's generally much more annoying to convert a `System::String` to a `std::string` than the other way around, due to `System::String` being a localized, wide character-based string, let's go with the path of least resistance.

```
if (textBox1->Text = gcnew String(un.c_str()) && textBox2->Text = gcnew String(pw.c_str())){
```

Now the values are of the same type, `System::String`. This exposes problem 2.

Problem 2: = is the assignment operator. This currently tries to assign `un` to `textBox1->Text`, not compare. You mean to write:

```
if (textBox1->Text == gcnew String(un.c_str()) && textBox2->Text == gcnew String(pw.c_str())){
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++ your assignment operator is '=' , your comparison operator is '=='.

You'll want to change your code to:  if (textBox1->Text == un && textBox2->Text == pw)

Comment: The error is still the same. Which is operand types are incompatible ("System::String ^" and "std::string")

Comment: That's because they *are* different types. [You are mixing C++ and CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) data types. This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718188/convert-from-stdstring-to-string Or straight from the horse's mouth: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235219.aspx

Comment: Thanks ! it helped !